# Unable to increase IIS 7.5 upload limit (still 404 error)

Tags: iis-7.5, upload

I need to be able to upload large files to an ASP.NET application. I knew that IIS 7.5, by default, enforces a 30MB request limit. And I know that IIS throws a 404 error when you try to upload a file larger than the upload limit.

I have tried both to set a 500MB upload limit in my application's `web.config` and double-checked IIS console's `Request Filter` for the 500MB upload limit, successfully.

I still get a 404 error with a file large 23.2MB

I'm writing on SF because I believe it's not an application problem but a server configuration problem. What more can I check?

Answer (score 0):

try the following in the web.config of your site. Look a the docs for what units the values are in.

in `<system.web>`

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="10000"/>
```

[MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

in   `<system.webServer>`

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
```

[MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh, I tried only the second part (when I referenced the application's web.config)